# Error while opening a file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open set of files from a specific folder. But while trying to open one of the files i get the attached Sign In pop-up. 
[email signin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyWA4.jpg)

I don't know how to get rid of this because we don't want someone to manually undo this, also, i'm cancelling the pop-up I get below pop-up

[image]

I just click No/Yes i get a Run time error.

But the designated file is open (Daily Testing Inventory file).

Here's my macro that I achieved so far:

```
Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False


MyFolder = "C:\"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")
Do While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile
DoEvents
Loop
```

I'm a newbie as far as Excel VBA is concerned. (Since I don't have enough reputation can't post all the images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off Alerts as well

better synatx as well

- use a Workbook object to hold the opened workbooks
- do your code
- close each Workbook (the code below does so without saving)
- then trigger your next loop

*code*

```
Sub recut()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim Wb As Workbook

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
.DisplayAlerts = False
End With

MyFolder = "C:\"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")
Do While MyFile <> ""
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile)
'do code
Wb.Close False
MyFile = Dir
Loop


With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
.DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but I don't want the Opened workbooks to be closed as there further actions to be taken. The "Window Sign In" doesn't appear but so does all the Workbooks.

Answer (score 2):

You are not reading the next file name. hence the loop is infinite.
Please add the following line above "DoEvents":

```
MyFile = Dir()
```

Comment: Thank you that worked but still I get the Pop-up for Sign In (1st image). How can I get past that?

Comment: for sign in prompt read this:https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10/sign-in-type-the-email-of-the-account-you-would/63532fb6-4bc9-46d5-8a79-2a3505e6e202